# Sizzle push apply

Tags: javascript, sizzle

Why would the Sizzle selector engine use `push.apply( results.... )` over `results.push(...)` it seems unnecessary to me. Can someone explain the motivation?

To elaborate, I've become interested in writing/borrowing bits from sizzle for a lighter weight selector engine. I figure I don't need some things like `:contains(text)` which would reduce the weight even further. So reading through the source I see

```
var arr = [],
    push = arr.push
    results = results || [];
 ....
 push.apply( results, context.getElementsByTagName( selector ) );
```

The code makes sense, except wouldn't it be simpler to use

```
results.push( context.getElementsByTagName( selector ) );
```

I don't intend to be naggy about such a minor convention, I just want to know if I'm missing something like a context issue.

Comment: Compare `var a = [1]; a.push([2,3]);` vs `a.push.apply(a, [2,3])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is instead of:

```
results.concat(array)
```

Because `concat` creates an extra array, but `push.apply` won't:

```
push.apply(results, array)
```

The `results` array is cached and no extra arrays are created.

But you could also do:

```
results.push.apply(results, array)
```

I'm not sure why the need for `arr`.

**Edit:**

I'm thinking the need for the extra `arr` might be to convert the pseudo-array that `getElementsByTagName` returns into a real array.

Comment: I don't follow the `concat` reference sorry. array.push returns the length of the new array, as far as I know it doesn't duplicate the array internally. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7

Comment: `concat` creates an extra array everytime you use it, `push` does not. See point 2 -- "Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array() where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name". -- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.4

Comment: Right! sorry, I wasn't thinking of `concat` as an alternative to push and totally missed your point. I was focusing on the use of apply (and wondering why you're bringing up a different function). That makes sense and would be faster!

Comment: So the inefficient version would be: `results.concat([].slice.call(context.getElementsByTagName(selector))`

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code again (after taking a break). Around line 205, Sizzle checks if the selector pattern is an ID and uses results.push

```
elem = context.getElementById( m );
results.push( elem );
return results;
```

Line 237 onwards is for Elements or Classes and uses `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` along with `push.apply( results, ... )`.

I assume its a short hand version of

```
for( elem in context.getElementsByClassName( m ) ) {
    results.push( elem );
}
```

As is the case in the Mozzila docs example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
// short hand
var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);
var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);

/* vs. simple loop based algorithm */
max = -Infinity, min = +Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] > max)
    max = numbers[i];
  if (numbers[i] < min) 
    min = numbers[i];
}
```

### EDIT:

From my original question `results.push( context.getElementsByTagName( selector ) );` would result in an unwanted Object. This pushes the one argument of type NodeList into results.

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3], b = [], c =[];
b.push( a ); // b.length = 1, now we have a multidimensional array
[].push.apply( c, a ); // c.length = 3, we now have a clean array, not a NodeList
```